# Number of different combinations.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

You have $24$ individuals and should create teams with $3$ individuals in each team. You should generate new teams $4$ times, and one individual cannot be in the same team with another individual more than $1$ time.

Is it possible to create enough unique teams?

How many unique teams can you create?

Comment: Well, What do you think??

Comment: I don't know! What do you think?

Comment: "I don't know" isn't a good enough starting point to work with.  Have you ever seen any similar problems like the [kirkman's schoolgirl problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirkman%27s_schoolgirl_problem)? Have you ever heard of [Steiner triple systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_triple_system) before? Can you come up with any interesting ways to organize your thoughts like [this related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104107/balanced-incomplete-block-design-for-magazine-editor/267393#267393)? (*hint: the answer to your question can be found in one of the links*)

Comment: Well, "I don't know" is actually the starting point for me. That is why I ended up on this forum. I simply don't know... I have not heard of Steiner triple systems. I don't know how I would apply it. the kirkman's schoolgirl problem seems to need an odd multiple of 3 for the number of "schoolgirls", which is not my case. I cannot come up with any interesting ways to organize my thoughts similar to the related question you linked. I do not have the knowledge to do that in a way that will help anyone with this problem. What about you @JMoravitz ? :)